# How to specify certain groups to add to TestFlight build

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I can't seem to specify *only* a singular group to a TestFlight build. Is there something else I need to do? There's a plus button in AppStore Connect, but every time I click it it just has me go through the Export Compliance steps and releases to everybody. Doesn't make any sense at all...

[image]
[image]